# IndexPath for row 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nsindexpath

I'd like to get the NSIndexPath for the row 0. How can I find out the correct NSIndexPath for the row 0? I'd like to set it in here: `let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(/*the indexPath for row 0*/) as NSManagedObject` Do you know how I can do this and would like to help me? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Perhaps as simple as `NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)` ? – As soon as  you type `NSIndexPath(` in Xcode, code completion suggestions should pop-up.

Comment: Yes it works. If you post it as an answer under this question I can accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

is what you are looking for.